# Using Substitute to replace several special characters

Tags: workflow, formula

I have a workflow rule field update action that concatenates two fields with a dot separating the two values:

`Style_Number__r.Name  + "."  +  Color__r.Name`

The field value for Color__r.Name can have several special characters...i.e. `&, \, &nbsp;, &nbsp; \ &nbsp;, -`

I wanted to use the Substitute function to replace those characters with an underscore `_` character.

So, if I have the value `1000.This&Is\A Crazy \ Color-Name` it would be converted to: `1000.This_Is_A_Crazy_Color_Name`

Is that possible using the Substitute function in a workflow action formula?

I was trying with one character: `Style_Number__r.Name  + "."  +  SUBSTITUTE(Color__r.Name, "\", "_")`

Is it possible to substitute multiple characters in a workflow action formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `SUBSTITUTE` on the result of the first `SUBSTITUTE`. You're essentially chaining them, until you return a final string.

```
Style_Number__r.Name  + "."  +  SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Color__r.Name, "\", "_"), "&", "_")
```